# Getting a callback from a radiobutton in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, callback, radio-button

I have a sipmle form with two radio buttons. By changing the selection I would like to execute some code in the callback function

[image: Exaple project with radiobuttons]

Here is my example code that does not work:

```
classdef radioexample < handle
    %radioexample2 
    % example for radiobuttons


    properties(Hidden)
        % all elements of the GUI are properties of the class trechner
        formMain;   % "The MainWindow"
        menuFile;   % "The Menu Header"

        % radio items
        radiogroup
        radio1
        radio2

    end

    methods(Hidden)
        function obj = radioexample 
            % Constructor Form Main
            obj.formMain = figure('position',[400,400,600,260],'Visible','off'); 
            set(obj.formMain,'Name','Radioexample','NumberTitle','off',...
                'MenuBar','none','Resize','Off');

            % a menu for exit the program            
            obj.menuFile.main = uimenu('Label','File');            
            obj.menuFile.exit = uimenu(obj.menuFile.main,...
                'Label','Exit','Callback',{@obj.close_Callback,obj});

            % radiobutton to select the mode
            obj.radiogroup = uibuttongroup(obj.formMain,...
                'Visible','on',...
                'Units','pixels',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'Position',[220 80 100 100]);
                %'SelectionChangedFcn',@obj.bselection);
            uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                'Style',...
                'radiobutton',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'String','Option 1',...
                'Position',[10 70 70 20],...
                'Callback',{@obj.opt1_Callback,obj},...
                'HandleVisibility','off');
            uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                'Style',...
                'radiobutton',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'String','Option 2',...
                'Position',[10 50 70 20],...
                'Callback',{@obj.opt2_Callback,obj},...
                'HandleVisibility','off');    

            set(obj.formMain,'Visible','on');
        end

    end

    methods(Static,Access=private)            
        function close_Callback(~,~,obj)  
            % close window
            close(obj.f)
        end

        function opt1_Callback(~)
            fprintf('switched to radio1 mode');  %Does not work
        end

        function opt2_Callback(~)
            fprintf('switched to radio2 mode');  %Does not work
            msgbox('switched to radio2 mode','Success'); %Does not work
        end

    end

    methods(Access=public,Hidden)
        function disp(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

The callback function does not get executed/called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easy to fix. Just do the following replacements in the `uicontrol`-line:

```
'Callback',@obj.opt1_Callback,...
```

and

```
'Callback',@obj.opt2_Callback,...
```

The callback function needs two input arguments. The first one is the uicontrol and the second one is the eventdata. If you don't need the input arguments, just add another `~` like this:

```
function opt1_Callback(~,~)
    fprintf('switched to radio1 mode');
end
```

and

```
function opt2_Callback(~,~)
    fprintf('switched to radio2 mode');
    msgbox('switched to radio2 mode','Success');
end
```

---

Another way is to use the `SelectionChangedFcn`-callback of the `uibuttongroup` like this:

```
classdef radioexample < handle
    %radioexample2 
    % example for radiobuttons


    properties(Hidden)
        % all elements of the GUI are properties of the class trechner
        formMain;   % "The MainWindow"
        menuFile;   % "The Menu Header"

        % radio items
        radiogroup
        radio1
        radio2

    end

    methods(Hidden)
        function obj = radioexample 
            % Constructor Form Main
            obj.formMain = figure('position',[400,400,600,260],'Visible','off'); 
            set(obj.formMain,'Name','Radioexample','NumberTitle','off',...
                'MenuBar','none','Resize','Off');

            % a menu for exit the program            
            obj.menuFile.main = uimenu('Label','File');            
            obj.menuFile.exit = uimenu(obj.menuFile.main,...
                'Label','Exit','Callback',{@obj.close_Callback,obj});

            % radiobutton to select the mode
            obj.radiogroup = uibuttongroup(obj.formMain,...
                'Visible','on',...
                'Units','pixels',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'Position',[220 80 100 100],...
                'SelectionChangedFcn',@obj.bselection);
            uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                'Style',...
                'radiobutton',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'String','Option 1',...
                'Position',[10 70 70 20],...
                'HandleVisibility','off');
            uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                'Style',...
                'radiobutton',...
                'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                'String','Option 2',...
                'Position',[10 50 70 20],...
                'HandleVisibility','off');    

            set(obj.formMain,'Visible','on');
        end

        function bselection(source,~,callbackdata)
            switch callbackdata.NewValue.String
                case 'Option 1'
                    radioexample.opt1_Callback(source,callbackdata);
                case 'Option 2'
                    radioexample.opt2_Callback(source,callbackdata);
            end
        end

    end

    methods(Static,Access=private)            
        function close_Callback(~,~,obj)  
            % close window
            close(obj.f)
        end

        function opt1_Callback(~,~)
            fprintf('switched to radio1 mode');
        end

        function opt2_Callback(~,~)
            fprintf('switched to radio2 mode');
            msgbox('switched to radio2 mode','Success');
        end

    end

    methods(Access=public,Hidden)
        function disp(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I changed it to your solution but the fprintfs are not executed when I change the radio selection.

Comment: @kimliv: There has been an error in the arguments and it is corrected now. It should have worked before anyways.

Comment: @kimliv Yes, it's tested with R2014b. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I run it on R2013a and get only this warnings: 
`Warning: Callback for uicontrol of style radiobutton will be overwritten when added to a UIBUTTONGROUP.
 Use the SelectionChangeFcn property on the button group instead. 
> In uitools.uibuttongroup.childAddedCbk at 12
  In radioexample>radioexample.radioexample at 37 
Warning: Callback for uicontrol of style radiobutton will be overwritten when added to a UIBUTTONGROUP.
 Use the SelectionChangeFcn property on the button group instead. 
> In uitools.uibuttongroup.childAddedCbk at 12
  In radioexample>radioexample.radioexample at 45`

Comment: @kimliv I added another method with the full code. I hope it works this time.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the standard way of doing it. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99842-why-do-i-receive-a-warning-message-when-i-copy-a-uibuttongroup-that-contains-radio-buttons-and-or-to

Comment: Ok, under R2015a this is working .... thank you and sorry for the irritation produced by R2013a ....